# cout value without touching variable C++

Tags: c++, stack, calling-convention

When I run the program, it prints the value of variable a. But when I comment the line '`cout<<&b<<endl<<&a<<endl;`' it prints a garbage value.
What can be the explanation behind it?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = 9;
    int b = 10;
    int *pb = &b;
    cout<<&b<<endl<<&a<<endl;
    cout<<*(pb+1);
}
```

Comment: *undefined behavior* - `*(pb+1);` accesses "out of bounds"

Comment: It is undefined behaviour, everything goes. And what has calling convention to do with this

Comment: Because `pb` points to a *single* `int` variable. When you do `*(pb+1)` it's equal to `pb[1]` which is attempting to use `pb` as an array and print the *second* value in the array. That is out of bounds of what `pb` points at and leads to *undefined behavior*. Undefined behavior makes your whole program *ill-formed* and invalid.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but do you really need the extra stuf that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you print the addresses of `a` and `b`, that forces the variables to actually have a memory address. Otherwise a value might be stored in a register, or not at all if never used.

It is a very common optimization for compilers to transform

```
const int a = 9;
cout << a;
```

into

```
cout << 9;
```

and never store `a` anywhere.

And anyway, there are no rules saying where and in what order the variables are to be stored in memory. That is totally up to the compiler. So your assumption that `&a == &b + 1` (or `&b - 1`) is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

There are two spots where you could get "gibberish" values however only one of them is actualy where garbage is printed out.

This `cout << &b << endl << &a << endl;` will print the addresses of `a` and `b` by using the address-of-operator. What you see there are not the values of `a` and `b` rather there locations where they are stored in memory. Those are hex values and they will probably change each time you run the program. This is the expected behaviour.

Then there is this construct: `*(pb + 1)` which is actually invoking undefined behaviour. But why is this? First of all `pb` is a pointer so it stores an adress, more specifically the memory address where `b` is stored. You can either print out `pb` directly which will result in the same thing as `cout << &b` or dereference it using the dereference operator `*`. So this `cout << *pb` would print the value not the address `pb` is pointing to (`10` btw). Now to what is wrong with your statement - `(pb + 1)` is not increasing the value `pb` is pointing but the address stored in `pb`. So it no longer points to the value of `b` but to some other value somewhere in the memory. Then you dereference this address and read some random value - this is your "garbage" value.

What you probably want is to increase the value `pb` is pointing to. So `cout << (*pb + 1)` will print `11` (note where the brackets are placed). But `cout << b` would still result in `10`. If you want to actually alter the value of b you could do this:

```
int b = 10;
int *pb = &b;
*pb += 1;
cout << b;
```

Now `b` was increased by one without touching `b` itself.

Answer (score -1):

The garbage value on your screen is the address of a and b . and you should try this :

```
int *pb = &b;
```

Comment: You're right that this `cout << &b << endl << &a << endl;` will print the adresses of `a` and `b`, but whatever you're trying to achieve with that "answer" will produce nothing but compiler errors.

Comment: Acc. to the question the person is just asking that the explaination behind it, not asking about any error !

Comment: _you should try this: `int *pb->&b;`_

What you are suggesting there is invalid syntax and will produce compiler errors! Btw. I'm not even sure what you are trying to suggest there.

Comment: I am just providing the correct syntax for assigning the value to a pointer.

Comment: _error: expected unqualified-id before ‘&’ token *pb->&b;_ As I said, this is incorrect syntax. If you want to assign a value to a pointer you do it like this `int *pb = &b`. That's the way it's always been.